# andengine mousejoint withouth gravity

Tags: android, andengine

How to keep all collision and acceleration effects, without gravity. I would like add a body that doesn't fall down to ground but if no collision append holds its position.

```
public class PhysicsMouseJointExample extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener, IOnSceneTouchListener, IOnAreaTouchListener {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    private static final FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;

    private TiledTextureRegion mBoxFaceTextureRegion;
    private TiledTextureRegion mCircleFaceTextureRegion;

    private Scene mScene;

    private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;
    private int mFaceCount = 0;

    private MouseJoint mMouseJointActive;
    private Body mGroundBody;

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Touch the screen to add objects.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources() {
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 64, 64, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_box_tiled.png", 0, 0, 2, 1); // 64x32
        this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_circle_tiled.png", 0, 32, 2, 1); // 64x32
        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        this.mScene = new Scene();
        this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 0, 0));
        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
        this.mScene.setOnAreaTouchListener(this);

        this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
        this.mGroundBody = this.mPhysicsWorld.createBody(new BodyDef());

        final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
        final Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle right = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH - 2, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, vertexBufferObjectManager);

        final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

        this.mScene.attachChild(ground);
        this.mScene.attachChild(roof);
        this.mScene.attachChild(left);
        this.mScene.attachChild(right);

        this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);

        return this.mScene;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGameCreated() {
        this.mEngine.enableVibrator(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
            switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    this.addFace(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
                    return true;
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(this.mMouseJointActive != null) {
                        final Vector2 vec = Vector2Pool.obtain(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
                        this.mMouseJointActive.setTarget(vec);
                        Vector2Pool.recycle(vec);
                    }
                    return true;
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(this.mMouseJointActive != null) {
                        this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyJoint(this.mMouseJointActive);
                        this.mMouseJointActive = null;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final ITouchArea pTouchArea, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
            final IAreaShape face = (IAreaShape) pTouchArea;
            /*
             * If we have a active MouseJoint, we are just moving it around
             * instead of creating a second one.
             */
            if(this.mMouseJointActive == null) {
                this.mEngine.vibrate(100);
                this.mMouseJointActive = this.createMouseJoint(face, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerationData.getX(), pAccelerationData.getY());
        this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
        Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeGame() {
        super.onResumeGame();

        this.enableAccelerationSensor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseGame() {
        super.onPauseGame();

        this.disableAccelerationSensor();
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    public MouseJoint createMouseJoint(final IAreaShape pFace, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        final Body body = (Body) pFace.getUserData();
        final MouseJointDef mouseJointDef = new MouseJointDef();

        final Vector2 localPoint = Vector2Pool.obtain((pTouchAreaLocalX - pFace.getWidth() * 0.5f) / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, (pTouchAreaLocalY - pFace.getHeight() * 0.5f) / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
        this.mGroundBody.setTransform(localPoint, 0);

        mouseJointDef.bodyA = this.mGroundBody;
        mouseJointDef.bodyB = body;
        mouseJointDef.dampingRatio = 0.95f;
        mouseJointDef.frequencyHz = 30;
        mouseJointDef.maxForce = (200.0f * body.getMass());
        mouseJointDef.collideConnected = true;

        mouseJointDef.target.set(body.getWorldPoint(localPoint));
        Vector2Pool.recycle(localPoint);

        return (MouseJoint) this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(mouseJointDef);
    }

    private void addFace(final float pX, final float pY) {
        this.mFaceCount++;
        Debug.d("Faces: " + this.mFaceCount);

        final AnimatedSprite face;
        final Body body;

        if(this.mFaceCount % 2 == 0) {
            face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        } else {
            face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        }
        face.setUserData(body);
        face.animate(200);

        this.mScene.registerTouchArea(face);
        this.mScene.attachChild(face);

        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================
}
```

I try to change gravity, but nothing seems to append.

```
    this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, -10), false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No gravity is:

```
enter code here`this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, 0), false);
```

This is anti-gravity or ~1G up:

```
this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, -10), false);
```

This is ~1G to the right:

```
this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(10, 0), false);
```

Comment: If i turn phone upside down or left-right my sprite must stay in its position. Changing with above values sprite still falling down.

Comment: Then you want the first one only. The Vector2 being passed to PhysicsWorld is to specify the left or right and the up or down "gravity" force. The first value is left/right. Negative values will make the sprites fall to the left side of the screen while positive values make the fall to the right side of the screen. The second value is up or top of screen for negative values and down bottom of screen for positive values. So if you pass in new Vector(0, 0), you are saying no gravity at all. Sprites will only move because of collisions or if you allow the user to fling them around.

Comment: I try changing the code as suggest - this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, 0), false) - but sprite still falling. I would like that sprite stay motionless when I tilt or rotate the phone

Comment: Looking further into your code I see you have a call to setGravity(). This is passing in "gravity" values based on the tilt of your device. If you don't want things to move as you tilt the device, remove the implements IAccelerationListener and related code and also don't bother with enabling or disabling the acceleration sensor.

Comment: Perfect! I delete all the code referring to acceleration and now nothing is falling. Thank you!